# Marking Rails migrations as migrated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration

I've ended up with 9 migrations effectively duplicated. (I think this is because I installed/updated Gems and/or pulled in their migrations on both my dev and production machines, but am not entirely sure at this stage.)

I moved out one set of the duplicated 9 from the rails directories on the production server, but now that I want to `db:migrate` on production in order to run another migration, I'm getting:

```
$ bundle exec rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
[DEPRECATION WARNING] Nested I18n namespace lookup under "activerecord.attributes.checkout" is no longer supported
==  CreatePages: migrating ====================================================
-- create_table(:pages)
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

Mysql2::Error: Table 'pages' already exists: CREATE TABLE `pages` (`id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY, `title` varchar(255), `body` text, `slug` varchar(255), `created_at` datetime, `updated_at` datetime) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

This is because the migrations have effectively already been run.

I'd rather avoid doing `db:migrate:down` and `db:migrate:up` for each one - I think this will mean data in the production database is lost. (A couple of static pages in Spree in this case.)

Is there a way I can tell this installation of Rails to forget all outstanding migrations, effectively marking all outstanding migrations as done?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can add the timestamps of the migrations to the schema_migrations table. However why is that table missing from the database or missing the rows it needs?

It is likely to be the case that this particular migration has got half way through and failed, thus when you are trying to run it again the first part of the migration will not work as it has been done previously. This is a limitation of MySQL as it can't rollback migration changes that fail part of the way through. Postgres on the other hand can rollback structural changes to the database thus avoiding this issue.

Comment: Thanks - this sounds like it should do the trick. I shall give it a try. I think I'm in this situation because the 9 migrations involved were created once each on both my dev and prod machines (thus what is effectively the same migration has two migrations each with its own timestamp). The first 9 were run, but then I've pulled in another 9 from my dev machine, hence the complaint about the table already existing. I'm still getting to grips with installing and updating Gems with regard to deployment.

Comment: Um, why do you have duplicate migrations which are the same but with different timestamps? The idea behind migrations is that you have one set of migrations (i.e. changes to the database structure) that everyone uses. The database then has a table to keep track of the migrations that have already run, thus they won't run twice on each environment (dev/production).

Comment: Indeed. I think this might be because I previously installed Gems (including their associated migrations) myself on both machines without realising the implication. I need to sort the workflow out.

Comment: In that case you just need to do the gem install, or even better have the gem mentioned in the Gemfile and use bundler to install the gem libraries. The first time setup rake script only needs to be run once when the gem is first added to the project.

Answer (score 23):

I solved it like this:

1. Go to the conflicting migration file.
2. Erase the content and save it.
3. Run `rake db:migrate`
4. Ctrl+Z the file to the previous state.

This was an special case, because I had copied the DB from another app, and I had conflicting migrations, and stuff.

Comment: yeah, this is a very good work around. Thanks. But I still wonder if there are some other solutions for this.

Comment: Wanted to add a clarification: Don't erase the whole content. Just delete everything between the class declaration and end. Deleting everything will result in this error due to a mismatch between filename and class name: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17776900/error-on-dbmigrate-uninitialized-constant-devisecreateusers

Comment: Instead of deleting content, comment out everything between the class declaration and end. Uncomment when finished migrating.

Answer (score 13):

You can also, in a Rails console, use the `ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration` model to add the timestamps into the schema_migrations table.

```rb
ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration.create! version: '20210724133241'
```

Answer (score 9):

By default `rake db:migrate` runs all the pending migrations. So, in order to get your migrations right.. for the sake ..comment out those migrations and afterwards revert those back to normal. It will ensure that you are ok in future migrations.